# Polymer elements in Windows HTML/JS app

Tags: windows, polymer

I'm wondering what the limitations are with using Polymer elements in a Windows 8 app built with a blank JavaScript project.

A quick test results in an error about loading dynamic content which makes sense. I'm also not sure how Polymer's polyfills would work with it.

Is there any way to do this? Just curious.

Comment: Since Microsoft uses Internet Explorer 10(?) as their browser engine and Polymer supports IE10+ it should generally work.